# Storing different types of documents in database architecture

Tags: mysql, mongodb, architecture

**Hello community,**

I am developing a system where users can create different types of documents with different templates populated with different datasets.

For example user can create invoices, nondisclosure agreements, master service agreements and so on. Templates can be created dynamically.

I am thinking on scalable solution that would allow to create unlimited number of templates.

Since templates are scalable horizontally (fields can be added to template at any moment), my bet is to work with MongoDB, where I would store template fields.

As an aggregate, I would use SQL database, so column called `documents` would exist there.

Example schema:

```
id int(11) unsigned
document_uuid varchar(36)
type enum
issuers_id int(11) unsigned FK
recipients_id int(11) unsigned FK
issued_at datetime
updated_at datetime
```

So basing on `document_uuid` field, I would fetch appropriate document from corresponding collection based on `type`.

Let's say there's following entry in SQL Database:

| id | document_uuid | type | issuers_id | recipients_id | issued_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3173b833-c8a1-4f4e-969d-1cce7db5d212 | invoice | 22 | 24 | 2021-06-07T21:15:07+00:00 | 2021-06-07T21:15:07+00:00 |

Flow:

1. User requests document of id 1
2. Backend handles request and selects document of id 1 from database
3. Backend picks `document_uuid` and `type` and seeks MongoDB for document of `document_uuid` in `type` collection
4. Backend consumes fields that comes from mongo db in order to generate an invoice from `ejs` template

My questions are:

1. Is it a well designed architecture to cover such functionality?
2. Is it reasonable to engage MongoDB here?
3. Is there any better approach for this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Storing each type in a separate collection would mean that you need unlimited collections to support unlimited templates, right?

Comment: @Joe that's right. I haven't thought about this, that's right. Any better ideas?

Comment: You are already storing the type with the other metadata in the SQL table, just store all of the documents in the same collection and query by UUID.  Since you just looked it up in the SQL table to get the UUID, you already know the type.